# Product creation date is in the future

Tags: magento-1.9, product, import

I'm seeing about 70ish products that have a creation date that is in the future. These products were imported through CSV, so maybe the date field in the import was incorrect?

Has anyone experienced something like this before, and does it have any affect on the products?

Is there any way to change the product creation date other than editing it in the database?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't affect your Magento store. But, still, if you want to change it, CSV Import/Export needs to be done. Following are the steps you can follow to change the ***created_at***

- Magento Admin Panel -> System -> Import/Export -> Export
- Choose Entity Type as Products
- Filter your products based on created_at, in the 5th row, where you'll find created_at (Attribute Code), select the current date in ***From***, and empty in ***To***
- Select ***Continue*** Button
- Download the CSV, open it in excel
- Change the dates in In 12th column of your CSV, which you may find, created-at (heading), change the values under it, where values exist
- After changing the values, Save the file
- Magento ***Admin Panel -> System -> Import/Export -> Import***
- Entity Type as Products
- Browse & locate the CSV file you changed and saved
- Check Data
- If *File is valid!*, Import

Answer (score 1):

I also sometimes encounter this problem, to fix the dates you can create a file called fixdates.php with the content below and upload it in the root folder of you Magento store. Then you can run it going to 
www.example.com/fixdates.php
(you should change the 2 dates according to your need, I'd suggest to set to the current day USA format)

```
<?php

require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('admin');
ignore_user_abort(true);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$collection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array("gt" => "2015-06-11"));

foreach($collection as $product){
    $p = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($product->getId());
    echo "<p>{$p->getName()} ({$p->getCreatedAt()})</p>";
    $p->setCreatedAt("2015-05-01");
    $p->save();
}
```